# Definition of Hausdorff measure by means of balls

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

The definition of Hausdorff measure $\mathcal{H}^s$ (for $s$ a non-negative real number) of a (Borel) measurable set $E \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is well-known. It reads as $\mathcal{H} ^ s(E)=\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \mathcal{H} ^ s _\varepsilon (E)$, where
$$ \mathcal{H} ^ s _\varepsilon (E) = \inf ~ \Big \{ 2^{-s} \sum_j (\mathrm{diam} F_j)^s : E \subset \bigcup _{j=1} ^\infty F_j , ~ \mathrm{diam}  F_k < \varepsilon \Big   \}.$$
My question is that, whether the definition of Hausdorff measure remains true, if one just consider  covering balls $B=B(x,r) \subset \mathbb{R}^d$? This is similar to the definition of standard Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

In this case, one can propose an alternative definition of $ \mathcal{H} ^ s _\varepsilon (E)$ (if not wrong, and after some normalizations) as below:
$$\inf ~ \Big \{ 2^{-s} \sum_j  (\mathrm{diam} B_j)^s : E \subset \bigcup _{j=1} ^\infty B_j ,~~ B=B(x,r_j), x \in \mathbb{R}^d,  r_j < \tfrac{1}{2}\varepsilon \Big   \} \\ \approx  \inf ~ \Big \{  \sum_j (r_j)^s : E \subset \bigcup _{j=1} ^\infty B_j ,~~ B=B(x,r_j), x \in \mathbb{R}^d,  r_j < \tfrac{1}{2}\varepsilon \Big   \}.$$
Are there examples, where the above definition of Hausdorff measure is not the same as the original definition?

Comment: Section 2.4 -- *Equivalent definitions of Hausdorff dimension* (pp. 32-33) of Falconer's **Fractal Geometry** (1990; see [here](https://people.brandeis.edu/~kleinboc/211a/FalconerCh2.pdf)) shows that using balls gives values between $\mathcal{H}^s$ and $2^s \mathcal{H}^s.$ Thus, while the measures (presumably) can differ, the corresponding dimension values are the same. See also [Inequality between Hausdorff measure and spherical Hausdorff measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1435254/13130) **(continued)**

Comment: It doesn't appear that Falconer gives an example showing the measure values **can** differ, but I suspect an example might be found by googling ["Falconer" + "equivalent definitions of Hausdorff dimension"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Falconer%22+%22equivalent+definitions+of+Hausdorff+dimension%22&filter=0).

Comment: [This answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/271839/15780) to the mathoverflow question *Is there a characterization of the Hausdorff measures?* states that the measure values are the same when the set is rectifiable, and says that an example where the measures can be different is in section 2.6 of Federer's **Geometric Measure Theory** (1969). Looking this up in my copy of Federer's book, I see that Federer gives references to several such examples on p. 174 and in section 3.3.21 on p. 309.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks for the detailed explanation, the reference to Federer's book. that was very helpful